# Making a list from the elements of multiple lists (numbers)

Tags: python, list

I am struggling to copy individual elements from a list into another list.

I want to select the first element from `a` and the first element of `b` into `c`.

```py
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
```

I want `c` to be `[1,4]`.

I have been trying this using code:

```py
Game_Pool = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

First_Values    = Game_Pool[0:4]
Last_Values     = Game_Pool[-4:-1]
            
Comb_01 = (First_Values[0] + Last_Values[0])
```

I need `Comb_01` to be `[1,5]`.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Since you know what indices you want to retrieve, you can just splice the lists and join them with `+`.

```
Comb_01=First_Values[0:1]+Last_Values[1:2]
```

gives

```
[1,5]
```

or

```
a[0:1]+b[0:1]
```

gives

```
[1,4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thankyou :-)

Also I just worked out

Comb_01 = [[First_Values[0],Last_Values[0]]]

Answer (score 0):

At the question, you should add a semicolon between the two assignments for `First_Values` and `Last_Values`, if you want to keep them in one line, otherwise you will get a syntax error. So

```py
First_Values = Game_Pool[0:4] Last_Values = Game_Pool[-4:-1]
```

should be

```py
First_Values = Game_Pool[0:4]; Last_Values = Game_Pool[-4:-1]
```

or just typing them in two separate lines

```py
First_Values = Game_Pool[0:4]
Last_Values = Game_Pool[-4:-1]
```

Another thing you may want to be careful about is that `Game_Pool[-4:-1]` does not include the member with index `-1` (the last member, here `8`). Python goes up to one before the last index. So if you ask python to show you `Last_Values`, you will get `[5,6,7]`.  To tell python to go till the end including the last member, just leave the second index of the slicing empty ^_^ That is `Game_Pool[-4:]`. Now this will also include `8`.

The reason that your `+` in your attempt at the question is not adding two lists at the end of each other is that the two things you put at its left and right sides are not lists, but just one member without any brackets. To be more exact, when you use slicing in brackets in front of name of a list, you will receive a sub-list. So `Game_Pool[0:4]` or `Game_Pool[-4:]` returns lists. But when you use number of one index inside the brackets in front of name of a list, it only returns you one member without any list wrapper. So `First_Value[0]` is just `1` which is an `int`, not a `list`. There are two ways to fix it. One way is to use slicing, so you could type `First_Values[0:1]` which gives you a sub-list with members of index starting from 0 and finishing one before 1, which means only index 0 is selected. Second way is to type brackets around this value yourself, that is `[First_Values[0]]`. Here are these two solutions.

**Solution 1**

```py
Game_Pool = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
First_Values = Game_Pool[0:4]
Last_Values = Game_Pool[-4:]
Comb_01 = [First_Values[0]] + [Last_Values[0]]
```

**Solution 2**

```py
Game_Pool = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
First_Values = Game_Pool[0:4]
Last_Values = Game_Pool[-4:]
Comb_01 = First_Values[0:1] + Last_Values[0:1]
```

Now, you also found a solution too which you posted in an answer. But just one tiny thing is that you typed one extra brackets. So with `Comb_01 = [[First_Values[0],Last_Values[0]]]` you will get `[[1,5]]`. Therefore the third solution is removing the extra brackets from your answer ^_^

**Solution 3**

```py
Game_Pool = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
First_Values = Game_Pool[0:4]
Last_Values = Game_Pool[-4:]
Comb_01 = [First_Values[0], Last_Values[0]]
```